# how to combine multiple rows into one row, while adding specific values from certain columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a snippet of the transaction data, am dealing with Python, pandas, towards classification work.
Customer_ID are unique for each customer and "entry time” is unique for each transaction. Any customer will have multiple transactions during a period of time.
Most transactions are repeated twice or more depending on how many tags are associated with a transaction (but usually 2 to 4 tags). 
I want to combine such multiple entries of a transaction to only 1 row, with 1 customer_ID, one gender, age, entry time and all the Tag attributes.

[snippet of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BUJu.png)

I have tried to group by customer_id and entry date but didn't get the desired result.

For example, customer_ID: 5519707 has four entries for just one transaction on 2019-04-27 16:07:05+00:00.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6VgF.png)

I want to replace these 4 rows with 1 row, as below:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9k8F.png)

So whats an efficient way to do this? as my dataset has 2.5 million rows and 30+ attributes, with a total size of 700MB.

Comment: You should groupby your data and then reduce the flags by summing them, if they are in fact unique.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one of the efficient ways if you want to consider the 'tag' columns .

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"an":["j","j","j","k","k"], "bn":[0,1,1,0,1], "cn":[2,1,2,3,1]})
df1.groupby(["an"])["bn", "cn"].sum().reset_index()
```

Input:

```
    an  bn  cn
0   j   0   2
1   j   1   1
2   j   1   2
3   k   0   3
4   k   1   1
```

Output :

```
    an  bn  cn
0   j   2   5
1   k   1   4
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in a way if i want to add the values of columns "bn" and "cn", but what if i have other columns, whose values are same across the 5 rows and need not be summed up, just picking the value from any one row will be fine for those columns. So what i want is sumup values of "bn" and "cn", but dont sumup values of "dn", "en".

Comment: I figured out the solution, had to keep the other columns which need not be summed inside the "groupby" brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['id']).max().reset_index()
```

INPUT

```
    id  gender  age tag1 tag2
0   200 male    20  0    1
1   200 male    20  1    0
2   200 male    20  0    0
```

OUTPUT

```
     id gender  age tag1 tag2
0   200 male    20  1    1
```

Comment: thanks for replying, however this doesnt works in this context. because customer with same ID has multiple transactions on various dates. I only want to groupby and sumup transactions with same timestamp, not sum or group or all transactions of a customer. when i tried this code, python was processing for 30+ minutes and never finished processing, so i had to restart the console.